# Is there any version of wamp server  usable on Windows-Vista(32-bit)?

Tags: windows-vista, wamp

I used WAMP 2.0 in XP,but I found  it doesn't work on Vista.And I wonder if there's any version of WAMP for Vista?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to install [**WampServer**](http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php). It's a bundle of Apache, MySQL and PHP running on Windows. You can try and test different versions of each.

[image]

According to [**this post at petri.co.il**](http://www.petri.co.il/install_wamp_server_on_vista.htm), it works on Vista.

Comment: @Snark: I have installed some versions as http://www.petri.co.il/install_wamp_server_on_vista.htm 
says,but failed.Maybe more should be tried.

Comment: What went wrong? Did you get error messages?

Comment: I cannot get that right now cuz I'm not beside my own PC .When installing there was some permission problem happened,then the install cannot continue. :(